# Is there a way to get Hit Counts in solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a simple question that is it possible to get hit counts in a document. like if we search "risk" could we get the count of risk in the matched document.

Comment: @ajreal: my index file has data indexed not stored, can we still get Hit Count, and secondly can we sort result on the basis of hit counts?

Comment: @ajreal: this is not about faceting at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [highlighting](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Highlighting) and count the snippets. Make sure you have termVectors enabled for the affected fields and understand the highlighting options.

You could also use the [TermVectorComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent), it's currently not directly [addressable via SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=68) though.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: using TermVectorComponenet could we sort data, on the baisis of hit count.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: is it possible to get the frequency of only those terms that are matched with the query? and secondly what if we only index data but not stored does term vectors still work or not

Comment: @Ahsan: using TermVectorComponent to sort data based on hit count: no. Solr naturally does that. If you need to control it take a look at boosting and function queries.

Comment: @Ahsan: get the frequency of only those terms that are matched with the query: no, due to stemming and other analysis steps the match is not always exactly the string that was searched, so in general it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ahsan: don't know if it will work on indexed non-stored fields... give it a try and let me know :-)

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: thanx for your help, and sure i will let u know after trying on indexed not stored data