# How do I store tags associated with a document in Solr and retrieve their frequency in aggregate?

Tags: tags, solr

I am using Solr to index documents from a wiki. Each document has a unique id, title, body content and some other fields.

Firstly, I wanted to know the declaration in the Solr schema to store the multivalued field "tags" to hold n of these strings, attached to the document. Each document can have a set of tags applied on it.

Second, the use case - how exactly would I retrieve all distinct tags across the entire Solr instance with number of occurences, so that I can build a tag cloud of most popular tags?

thanks 
Amit

Comment: repeated question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956/how-to-get-facet-ranges-in-solr-results

Comment: @ajreal - I understand the straight faceting aspect, but the question here is about aggregation across the index, of a multivalued field, returning distinct occurences, with frequency of occurence

Comment: as pointed by @Mauricio Scheffer , facet might not related - for your scenario, assuming u have field `status` and `tags` (multiValued), u can try `q=status:live&facet=true&facet.field=tags&facet.mincount=5..` what it does it basically look-up for document with status live, and return `tags` count (this tag count is based on results return by `q`), not sure is it closer to what u want

Comment: if u looking for Hitcount, answer by @Mauricio Scheffer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143896/is-there-a-way-to-get-hit-counts-in-solr is probably what u need